# .data() JQuery returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

im working with my first webapp, Im using ajax parsed object to add dynamic content to one specific .html... while doing so, I found an issue with adding data-* attribute to every option on a select dropdown... when the change function from JQuery executes, it returns undefined.

Here is my ajax function, (I know its not the best way to do it).

```
ajaxPost("link/x.php",{},function(result){
            var json=JSON.parse(result);
            var resultado=json.response;
            if(json.error==0){
            var estadosString='<option value=""></option>';
            var cont=0;
                for(estado in resultado){
                   estadosString+=('<option value="'+resultado[estado].nombre+'">'+resultado[estado].nombre+'</option>');
                }
                $('#estados').html(estadosString);
                cont=0;
                $('#estados option').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('data-id',cont);
                    $(this).data('id',cont++);

                });

            }else{
              alert("No hay estados");
            }
        });
```

The data-id attribute is sucefully added to each option, the issue starts when I use this code to get data-id on change select option.

```
$('#estados').on('change',function(){
            alert($(this).data("id"));

        });
```

It always return undefined, anyone can help me? Thanks..!

Comment: `alert($(this).children(':selected').data("id"));`

Comment: This line of code solved my issue, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

The value of `this` in that "change" handler will be the `<select>` element, not the `<option>` it's set to. You can find the option element via the select element's `selectedIndex` property, or via jQuery.

There's no reason to set the "data-id" attributes either; just set the value via `.data()`.

Comment: Yes sir, that was just a sad attempt to solve it, ignoring that line, can you please point me a simple code of how the change handler should look like? Thanks!!

Comment: The code that @A Wolff posted in the comment should do it!